# Convert copied node to string in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, string, xslt

Using an XSLT file in XSLT 1.0 (and purely 1.0), I am working with XML files, and have used the following code so far to copy a given node from a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/Heading/subsection/information"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I want to convert this copied node/everything within the node to a string and return it within a parameter, but for the string conversion itself I am unsure of how to proceed with it and present it as I need all the information within the node as a string as opposed to a single line

The end result would be going from the original node of

```
<information>
  <stuff>this is a message</stuff>
  <stuff2>another message</stuff2>
</information>
```

to the string(s):

```
information
stuff this is a message
stuff2 another message
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want to set the output mode to text:

```
<xsl:output mode="text" />
```

This is optional, but makes sense if you goal is to create a regular text document and don't want the output to be XML-escaped.

Then add a template for `<information>` elements that outputs multiple lines (manually add the newline `&#xa;`):

```
<xsl:template match="information">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '&#xa;')" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(stuff, '&#xa;')" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(stuff2, '&#xa;')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Possible variants would be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '&#xa;', stuff, '&#xa;', stuff2, '&#xa;')" />
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="name()" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="stuff" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="stuff2" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```